# Complexity analysis for the permutations algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, computer-science, space-complexity

I'm trying to understand the time and space complexity of an algorithm for generating an array's permutations. Given a partially built permutation where `k` out of `n` elements are already selected, the algorithm selects element `k+1` from the remaining `n-k` elements and calls itself to select the remaining `n-k-1` elements:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> permutations(List<Integer> A) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    permutations(A, 0, result);
    return result;
  }

  public static void permutations(List<Integer> A, int start, List<List<Integer>> result) {
    if(A.size()-1==start) {
      result.add(new ArrayList<>(A));
      return;
    }

    for (int i=start; i<A.size(); i++) {
      Collections.swap(A, start, i);
      permutations(A, start+1, result);
      Collections.swap(A, start, i);
    }
  }
```

My thoughts are that in each call we swap the collection's elements `2n` times, where `n` is the number of elements to permute, and make `n` recursive calls. So the running time seems to fit the recurrence relation `T(n)=nT(n-1)+n=n[(n-1)T(n-2)+(n-1)]+n=...=n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2)+...+n!=n![1/(n-1)!+1/(n-2)!+...+1]=n!e`, hence the time complexity is `O(n!)` and the space complexity is `O(max(n!, n))`, where `n!` is the total number of permutations and `n` is the height of the recursion tree.

This problem is taken from the Elements of Programming Interviews book, and they're saying that the time complexity is `O(n*n!)` because "The number of function calls `C(n)=1+nC(n-1)` ... [which solves to] `O(n!)` ... [and] ... we do `O(n)` computation per call outside of the recursive calls".

Which time complexity is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of this algorithm, counted by the number of basic operations performed, is `Θ(n * n!)`. Think about the size of the `result` list when the algorithm terminates-- it contains `n!` permutations, each of length `n`, and we cannot create a list with `n * n!` total elements in less than that amount of time. The space complexity is the same, since the recursion stack only ever has `O(n)` calls at a time, so the size of the output list dominates the space complexity.

If you count only the number of recursive calls to `permutations()`, the function is called `O(n!)` times, although this is usually not what is meant by 'time complexity' without further specification. In other words, you can generate all permutations in `O(n!)` time, **as long as you don't read or write those permutations** after they are generated.

The part where your derivation of run-time breaks down is in the definition of T(n). If you define T(n) as 'the run-time of `permutations(A, start)` when  the input, A, has length `n`', then you can not define it recursively in terms of T(n-1) or any other function of T(), because the length of the input in all recursive calls is `n`, the length of A.

A more useful way to define T(n) is by specifying it as the run-time of `permutations(A', start)`, when A' is any permutation of a **fixed, initial array A**, and A.length - start == n. It's easy to write the recurrence relation here:

```
T(x) = x * T(x-1) + O(x)     if x > 1
T(1) = A.length
```

This takes into account the fact that the last recursive call, T(1), has to perform `O(A.length)` work to copy that array to the output, and this new recurrence gives the result from the textbook.